# Replace the page url with a menu link?

Tags: menus, multi-language, language, customization

i want to make a multilangual site, where the secondary language is a copy of the site in a different folder. For example:

- Primary language url: `example.com`
- Secondary language url: `example.com/en`

So there are two websites with the same content, only the language and the directory are different.

**I want to create a *"language switcher menu item"* that dynamically changes the page url.** For example:

- if i'm on the `example.com/about` page after clicking the "*language switcher menu item*", i want to go to the `example.com/en/about` page.
- so all it have to do is that this menu item dynamically changes the current page's url (it replaces the original domain from `example.com/` to `example.com/en`), and it does not modify the rest of the url (the url structure on the two sides is of course the same)

I hope I have been able to describe it clearly.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You'd need to include some of your code... ...this could be done a number of different ways but ultimately that decisions is best informed by viewing the existing code you're working with.

Comment: which part of the code do you need? The best would be if there was code that works in general (template independent) ... But I'm open to any solution :)